# Checking if an expression is divisible by 3

Tags: number-theory

How can I check if the following expression is divisible by 3?

$$
{100 \choose 0}2^0 + {100 \choose 1}2^1 + {100 \choose 2}2^2 + ... +{100 \choose 100}2^{100}
$$

Does it suffice to check that if a particular term is not divisible by 3, then the entire expression is not divisible by 3?

Comment: No, consider the expression $4+5=9$. Both the terms are not divisible by 3 but the whole expression is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

It is much simpler, since it is a binomial expansion. Guess which?

Comment: $$(1+2)^{100} = 3^{100}$$ So it is divisible by 3?

Comment: Do you know any power of $3$ not divisible by $3$? ;o)

Answer (score 0):

You could try computing the examples with $1, 2, 3$ instead of $100$, which might help you to recognise the hidden form here.

Answer (score 0):

........Hint:

$2^k=2^k1^{100-k}$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to compute the remainder when that sum is divided by $3$,

without recognizing that sum as a binomial expansion.

Using [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula) to calculate the power of $3$ dividing ${100 \choose n}=\frac{100!}{n!(100-n)!}$ shows that

$3$ divides ${100 \choose n}$ for all $n$ from $0$ to $100$ except for $0, 1, 9, 10, 18, 19, 81, 82, 90, 91, 99,$ and $100$.

Since we can subtract a multiple of $3$ without affecting divisibility by $3$, the question now becomes

is $\binom{100}02^0+\binom{100}12^1+\binom{100}92^9+\binom{100}{10}2^{10}+\binom{100}{18}2^{18}+\binom{100}{19}2^{19}$

$+\binom{100}{81}2^{81}+\binom{100}{82}2^{82}+\binom{100}{90}2^{90}+\binom{100}{91}2^{91}+\binom{100}{99}2^{99}+\binom{100}{100}2^{100}$  divisible by $3$.

Note that the remainder when $2^n$ is divided by $3$ is $1$ when $n$ is even and $2$ when $n$ is odd.

The next step in this approach is to find the remainder when $\binom{100}n$ is divided by $3$

for $n\in\{0,1,9,10,18,19,81,82,90,91,99,100\}$.

To find, e.g., the remainder when $\binom{100}9$ is divided by $3$, note $\binom{100}9=\frac{100\times99\times98\times97\times96\times95\times94\times93\times92}{9\times8\times7\times6\times5\times4\times3\times2\times1};$

the remainders of $100, 98, 97, 95, 94, $ and $92$ divided by $3$

are the same as those of $1, 2, 4, 5, 7, $ and $8$ divided by $3$;

and $\frac{99\times96\times93}{9\times6\times3}=11\times16\times31$ leaves remainder $2$ when divided by $3$.

The question is now whether the following expression is divisible by $3$:

$1\times1+1\times2+2\times2+2\times1+1\times2+1\times1$

$+\,1\times1+1\times2+2\times1+2\times2+1\times2+1\times1.$